# First course table to add a field open, type Boolean；rake db:migrate Operation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

```
class AddOpenAttributeToCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :courses, :open, :boolean
    change_column_default(:courses, :open, {:from=>true, :to=>false})
  end
end
```

!!!!!then Operation!!!!!!

```
rake db:migrate
== 20161126133112 AddOpenAttributeToCourses: migrating ========================
-- add_column(:courses, :open, :boolean)
   -> 0.1047s
-- change_column_default(:courses, :open, {:from=>true, :to=>false})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "---
:from: true
:to: false
"
: ALTER TABLE "courses" ALTER COLUMN "open" SET DEFAULT '---
:from: true
:to: false
'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:455:in `change_column_default'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20161126133112_add_open_attribute_to_courses.rb:4:in `change'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "---
:from: true
:to: false
"
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question to tell us exactly what you intended to do and what were the expected results? Posting a class and an error message is hardly a good description of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use the [Rails5 arguments to `change_column_default`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default):

> **change_column_default**(table_name, column_name, default_or_changes)
>   [...]
>   Passing a hash containing `:from` and `:to` will make this change reversible in migration:
>
> ```
> change_column_default(:posts, :state, from: nil, to: "draft")
> ```

with [Rails4](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default):

> **change_column_default**(table_name, column_name, default)
>   Sets a new default value for a column: [...]

The funny looking stuff you see in the SQL:

```
---
:from: true
:to: false
```

is the YAML version of your `{ :from => true, :to => false }` Ruby Hash BTW.

You need to use separate `up` and `down` methods and simpler version of `change_column_default` with Rails4:

```
def up
  change_column_default(:courses, :open, false)
end
def down
  change_column_default(:courses, :open, true)
end
```

or just set the default when you create the column:

```
class AddOpenAttributeToCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :courses, :open, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

BTW, since you didn't specify a `:default` when you added the column it would have a default of `null`, not `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the column and set a default in one line:

```
add_column :courses, :open, :boolean, default: true
```

Not sure exactly why you're getting that error. Maybe it's because you say "change the default from false to true" but the default was *not* false, actually it was `nil`.